# How to fix empty space between arrow and multiline text?

Tags: css, flexbox

Inside a flexbox block I have multiline text and this text fills all width

[image]

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
</div>
```

```css
.list {
    width: 160px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.item::after {
    content: "→";
    align-self: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/in-in/pen/XVBqLw

Comment: is it a must to have flex?

Comment: You will need a script for this, if the text will be dynamic.

Comment: Since `display: flex` will create an anonymous box around the text, that box won't resize to fit its content when the text wraps, which is how the box model works, so script is needed here.